# SSRS Report Fails to Load in .net Report Application

Tags: asp.net, .net, reporting-services, web-config, ssrs-2008

We have a custom .net Report Application that is attempting to load a slightly data intensive SSRS report. Strangely, the report runs fine and returns data, albeit a little slow, when it is ran through the Report Manager and Mozilla Firefox. The problem is when a user attempts to load it through the Report Application in IE9, when all parameters are selected to maximize the data returned (20k rows), the report gets stuck on the Loading animation. The browser ultimately freezes and needs to be force-closed. There is no time-out time specified in the dataset of the report object itself, nor are any time-out settings specified in Report Manager. The Report Server execution logs show a TimeDateRetrieval and TimeProcessing time that indicates the report is loading successfully. Our belief is that there is a setting on the Report App that needs to be tweaked.

We have already configured the httpRunTime parameter in the web.config file to:

```
 <httpRuntime executionTimeout = “600”>
```

We have also attempted configuring the ViewReport.aspx file as follows

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="0"> </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the script manager was timing out you would see a loading indicator turn into a blank screen with a log entry in ssrs indicating the client has disconnected. I don't think this is your issue. It almost seems like the server has discontinued communication in your case. The SSRS has a site wide timeout, the report has two settings that pertain to render and query timing. The report has an execution timeout for rendering, whereas the dataset of the report has a query timeout. However, I would think if any of the ssrs timing conditions triggered an error you would get that in the postback.

Comment: Can you run the report in SSRS manager with all of your parameters? I recently had to increment an ajax scriptmanager's timeout in a legacy app to 9 minutes. If the report is rendered in SSRS without problems then there is likely a communication error between the server your app is on and the server rendering the report.

Comment: The report loads when less parameters are selected and hence less data is returned.  We are leaning towards this being a server related issue.  It looks like we'll be consulting MSFT.  Time to get the logs ready :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the ASyncPostBackTimeout property setting was altered in the Report Viewer module.  Reverting it to ASyncPostBackTimeout="0" did the trick.  It did have to do with the script manager.